# How can I embed an MP3 on my Google App Engine website?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, audio-streaming

I have a system that accepts MP3 uploads to the BlobStore, and now I would like to embed them in an HTML5 player.  The trouble is: I can't seem to get a link directly to the MP3 file.  I've used `images.get_serving_url(blob_key)` to great effect, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for audio files.

The documentation explains how to create a handler that serves any file from the blobstore, with two slightly different approaches: [BlobstoreDownloadHandler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.html#BlobstoreDownloadHandler) and [Sample App](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Complete_Sample_App)

Both had the same result for me, which you can see here: http://testgroovebug.appspot.com/v1/audioserve?resource=AMIfv96sdSSVnSIVZXGyeeGDs3ZjbH7dy4mZmeuU_bUPYxxPu9KHrgO-VC4cVxAAYE-MsZmyuBfVRmFHAnlxLxQxhLMpvfBbCRNPjuriSIBCwO5dLTVpo3ncOL7uQI8VBo8KddW19gtUUU_IUr2AN_Er6BZxTwnmvg

This is supposed to be a 3+ minute song, but usually only the first few seconds come through.  Refreshing the page will randomly change the amount that is streamed (sometimes you get lucky and 10 seconds play!).

The HTTP header (gotten via curl) looks like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: audio/mpeg
< Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2011 18:48:52 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to use an embedded player of some kind.  However, the following code yields a big X in firefox.

```
<audio src="..." controls="controls">
</audio>
```

Comment: The url that you posted is restricted to admins only

Comment: Firefox doesn't support mp3 in the audio tag

Comment: Thank you very much, Shay.  Those were both of my issues!  Unbelievable that Firefox doesn't support MP3s.

Comment: Also this might be http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3219 (" Unable to stream audio blob on app engine")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the mp3 are accessible to everyone.
2. Because of licensing issues mp3 is not available on Firefox audio tag, you will need to store your files as ogg in order for them to work on Firefox.